# Proper way to pre-fill form after server-side validation failure, involving two separate php files

Tags: php, validation

A very basic question. I have a form in one file `form.php`, I post it to another file `processForm.php` which does the server-side validation and processing. I am not using any framework.

Now, in case of form validation failure, I need to display the form again with all the values prefilled, without using a javascript `history.back()` from the `processForm.php`. What is the clean and proper way to do this so that I have all the posted values available again in `form.php` and can prefill them?

This is easy if the form submission happens to the same page, but this is how I got this and I cannot make the submission into the same page. So what would you do? Store the values in session? Curl post? Send the values using `GET` to `form.php`?

Why or why not? Please mention pros and cons.

Answer (score 0):

Go read up on the MVC pattern.

You can't implement an interactive program without implementing a model, a view and a controller - the point is that your code should be structured to implement each of the three concerns as a single entity, be that as functions (or function trees), classes (or class trees) or files. And the three components within the pattern should be structurally grouped.

So if you want to the user to arrive at (say) second page after successfully filling in a form at first page, but to stay on first page when the form fails the validation, then a simple way to implement this would be to have first page implement the model view and controller, i.e. to both populate/generate the form and be the target for the form. Then if it receives a valid request sent from the form, send a redirect to second page.

This avoids the need for each page to load and process the MVC code for the preceding page *as well as* the current one - although that approach reduces the number of round trips to the browser which can help with performance.

NB using POST does not preclude the use of variables in the URL - indeed, I recommend using GET variables to indicate the data you wish to manipulate and POST variables to show how they should be manipulated.